# Canvas toDataURL Security error for same origin image

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, todataurl

I'm using html5 canvas for my web app. In order to getting rid of canvas security error, i redownload cross-origin image in my php server and get it on canvas via my site url.

For example i'm using http://myapp.com:8888/mapper?url=http://othersite.com/image.jpg

my php code:

```
    $url = $this->input->get('url');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, authorization, content-type);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age:1000');
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');

    $a = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $a;
```

Even if i'm trying to load image via my server url and add this access-control-allow headers, it gives security error when i call canvas.toDataURL();

I'm using http://myapp.com:8888 as url because i test it in localhost. Can it cause the error?

Comment: The CORS headers are only needed for cross domain requests, if you calling from your own sever then its not a cross domain request. Remove the CORS headers.

Comment: But without these headers it also gives security error when i call canvas.toDataURL()